# python: reading executable's stdout, broken stream

Tags: c++, python, stream, stdout, redirect

I am trying to read the output of an executable (A) which is written in c++ from my python script. I am working in Linux. The only way I have known so far is through the subprocess library

Firstly I tried

```
p = Popen(['executable', '-arg_flag1', arg1 ...], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
print "reach here"
stdout_output = p.communicate()[0]
print stdout_output
sys.stdin.read(1)
```

which turned out to hang up both my executable (with 99% cpu usage) and my script :S:S:S
Moreover reach here is printed.

After that I tried:

```
f = open ("out.txt",  'r+')
command = 'executable -arg_flag1 arg1 ... '
subprocess.call(command,  shell=True, stdout=f)
f.seek(0)
content = f.read()
```

and this works but I get an output where some chars at the end of the content are repeated or even more values produced than expected :S

Anyway could someone enlighten me of a more proper way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The first solution is best. Using shell=True is slower, and has security issues.

The problem is Popen doesn't wait for the process to complete, so Python stops leaving the process without stdout, stdin and stderr. Causing that process to go wild. Adding p.wait() should do the trick!

Also, using communicate is a loss of time. Just do stdout_output = p.stdout.read(). You'll have to check yourself if stdout_output contains anything though, but this is still nicer than using communicate()[0].

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to mention that I have a sys.stdin.read(1) after p.communicate as shown in the edited post, so the python script also hangs up along with the c++ executable. 
Anyway I tried added p.wait instead (both after p.Popen and then after p.communicate), with no luck. 
Moreover I should mention that "reach here" is printed. 
Finally I tried p.stdout.read() instead of communicate, no luck again :(